# About servlets in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets

These are the errors in my picture. I do not know how to work with it, and I have tried to change the library, but without success.

[image: picture]

Please help me if you can.

Thank you.

Comment: Add the exception stack trace and code

Comment: This is my pic https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn08U.png

Comment: Add them as code in the question, not as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be more of an issue with your eclipse work-space or the way you have created the project. You should check your build path and make sure all the libraries are present.

Also in your left pane, i don't see any Reference Libraries which would list down all the libraries in use.